# Twig ternary operator, Shorthand if-then-else

Tags: php, twig, conditional-operator

Does Twig support ternary (shorthand if-else) operator?

I need some conditional logic like:

```
{%if ability.id in company_abilities %}
    <tr class="selected">
{%else%}
    <tr>
{%endif%}
```

but using shorthand in Twig.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

```
{{ (ability.id in company_abilities) ? 'selected' : '' }}
```

The ternary operator is documented under '[other operators](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators)'

Comment: This is very helpful in situations like marking a button or item as active for the current page.

Comment: If TRUE, how do you go about printing ability.id? (in place of "selected").

Comment: @gdaniel `{{ (ability.id in company_abilities) ? ability.id : '' }}`

Comment: thanks. I have been having issues printing twig variables when inside inline conditionals. I will give this a try.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is supposed to be able to work inline to add an attribute value like a css class?  It does not seem to work for me:
`<div class="my-section {{ model.event.eventDate ? 'half' :  '' }}">`
--_wanting to add a css class here based on the condition._

Comment: @Jordan this is correct. If `model.event.eventDate` evaluates to true, it'll add the class. From twig's point of view, it does not know anything about classes, just prints strings, no matter if classes, IDs, raw HTML or whatever needed. Even more, it does not know about "printing". This is due to the `{{ }}`. It's just an expression that is evaluated as any other expression, like a sum, like a filter, like a method call.

Answer (score 141):

You can use shorthand syntax as of Twig 1.12.0

```
{{ foo ?: 'no' }} is the same as {{ foo ? foo : 'no' }}
{{ foo ? 'yes' }} is the same as {{ foo ? 'yes' : '' }}
```

Comment: Where in the documentation does it show the second example?? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 123):

Support for the extended ternary operator was added in **Twig 1.12.0**.

1. If `foo` echo `yes` else echo `no`:

   ```
   {{ foo ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
   ```
2. If `foo` echo it, else echo `no`:

   ```
   {{ foo ?: 'no' }}
   ```

   or

   ```
   {{ foo ? foo : 'no' }}
   ```
3. If `foo` echo `yes` else echo nothing:

   ```
   {{ foo ? 'yes' }}
   ```

   or

   ```
   {{ foo ? 'yes' : '' }}
   ```
4. Returns the value of `foo` if it is **defined** and **not null**, `no` otherwise:

   ```
   {{ foo ?? 'no' }}
   ```
5. Returns the value of `foo` if it is **defined** (**empty** values also count), `no` otherwise:

   ```
   {{ foo|default('no') }}
   ```

Answer (score 8):

If the price exists from the database for example then print (Price is $$$) else print (Not Available) and `~` for the concatenation in `Twig`.

```
{{ Price is defined ? 'Price is '~Price : 'Not Available' }}
```

Comment: If `Price` is equal to 0 it will evaluate to false and display 'Not Available' instead of 0, doesn't it?

Comment: i have changed to is defined

Answer (score 1):

I just used `a` as a general variable name. You can also use endless if else like this:

```
{{ a == 1 ? 'first' : a == 2 ? 'second' : 'third' }}
```