# Is there a Twig shorthand syntax for outputting conditional text

Tags: php, twig

Is there a shorter syntax in Twig to output a conditional string of text?

```
<h1>{% if not info.id %}create{% else %}edit{% endif %}</h1>
```

Traditional php is even easier than this:

```
<h1><?php info['id']? 'create' : 'edit' ?></h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary operators in Twig php (Shorthand form of if-then-else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820297/ternary-operators-in-twig-php-shorthand-form-of-if-then-else)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

This should work:

```
{{ not info.id ? 'create' : 'edit' }}
```

Also, this is called the ternary operator. It's kind of hidden in the documenation: [twig docs: operators](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators)

From their documentation the basic structure is:

```
{{ foo ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

Comment: It looks like "if" will not work since the code is not wrapped in the statement delimiter {% %}. Omitting "if" averts the exception above.

Comment: You're right, I just did a test here and the 'if' is implicit.

Comment: problem if foo not defined

Comment: In a ternary why would you ever do this?

{{ not info.id ? 'create' : 'edit' }}

Just apply the logic in a straightforward manner.

{{ info.id ? 'edit' : 'create' }}

The 'not' operation just confuses the issue - you have to specify both outcome strings anyway, why make the code ever so slightly harder to read by doing negation when not needed?

Comment: `{{ foo_val ? foo_val : (bar_val ? bar_val : "default") }}` also works, not the prettiest thing, though.

Comment: Yes, this works! 
Perfect for input preset value validation (`value="{{ person.curp is not null ? person.curp : '' }}"`)

Answer (score 43):

If you need to compare the value is equal to something you can do :

```
{{  user.role == 'admin' ? 'is-admin' : 'not-admin' }}
```

You can use the Elvis Operator inside twig :

```
{{  user ? 'is-user' }} 

{{  user ?: 'not-user' }} // note that it evaluates to the left operand if true ( returns the user ) and right if not
```

Comment: The so called Elvis operators don't work. I get an error about wrapping the island in parens

Comment: @TheRealChx101 not sure what you mean by `wrapping the island in parens` - could you share your example?

Comment: Wrapping the IF code island in parentheses. I think it could be the version I'm using. It's actually JTWIG (Java version) but that shouldn't matter much.

Comment: not familiar with Java, it could be related to your framework/jtwig but I doubt it. its worth mentioning although all answers to this questions are correct i prefer to use a normal if/else statement most of the times, does that work for you? sorry I can't help much here.. good luck!

Comment: if you're curious about the `code island parens` referred to above - it's a jtwig thing, and is about using `{% ... %}` https://jtwig.gitbooks.io/jtwig-reference-manual/content/syntax/basic.html

Answer (score 6):

The [null-coalescing operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) also working, like:

```
{% set avatar = blog.avatar ?? 'https://example.dev/brand/avatar.jpg' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often, you can use [default](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/default.html) for this job.

```
{{ foo|default('bar') }}
```

Which is roughly equivalent to:

```
<?php echo isset($foo) ? $foo : $bar; ?>
```

It may not exactly be what the OP wanted, but I think it will come in handy for a closely related need with others.