# Twig shorthand conditionally set variable

Tags: php, twig, conditional-operator

From this question we know how to use a ternary operator to output conditional text: [Is there a Twig shorthand syntax for outputting conditional text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336090/is-there-a-twig-shorthand-syntax-for-outputting-conditional-text)

Example:

```
{{ foo ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

How can we use a ternary operator to conditionally set a variable, without outputting it directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
{% set foo = foo ? 'yes' : 'no' %}
```

Note you need to use `{% %}` instead of `{{ }}` and add the `set` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

You try

```
{{ foo is defined ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

or

```
{% if foo is defined %}
    {{ foo ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
{% endif %}
```