# How to set a html attribute + value via ternary?

Tags: symfony, twig

I've tried countless options, but I never get the quotes to wrap around the entire value as soon as there's a space within the value string:

```
{% set result_string= elements
        ? ( "data-custom-attribute=%s"|format( elements ) )
        : ''
%}
```

How can you make this work to get for example `data-custom-attribute="this is a test"` with elements having the value `'this is a test'` ?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336090/is-there-a-twig-shorthand-syntax-for-outputting-conditional-text

Comment: This is totally useless for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter `format` will not add any quotes to the example you've added in your snippet.

You are probably verifying your output in some developer tools which give a false-positive. Verify your output with the generated source (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>)

Either add the quotes in the variable `elements` or add them in your `html` snippet:

```
{% set elements = "\"foo bar foo\"" %}
{% set result_string= elements
        ? ( "data-custom-attribute=%s"|format( elements ) )
        : ''
%}
```

---

```
{% set elements = "foo bar foo" %}
{% set result_string= elements
        ? ( "data-custom-attribute=\"%s\""|format( elements ) )
        : ''
%}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/3f5wew)