# Optimize an 'if else' statement in twig

Tags: html, performance, symfony, if-statement, twig

I have the following code:

```
<div class="other_left_array" >
      {% if followeds.followeds_posts_counts[key] > 0 %}
        <a id="2"  href="javascript:void(0);" class="left_array_trigger">
            la
        </a>
      {% else %}
        <a id="2" style="display: none" href="javascript:void(0);" class="left_array_trigger">
            la
        </a>
      {% endif %}
   </div>
```

I feel there is another more optimal way to write such a code, especially that the only difference between the two statements is : `style="display: none"`. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820297/ternary-operators-in-twig-php

Comment: thank you Nick, this is it, ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the if statement in that place:

```
<div class="other_left_array" >
    <a id="2" {% if followeds.followeds_posts_counts[key] > 0 %}style="display: none"{% endif %}  href="javascript:void(0);" class="left_array_trigger">
        la
    </a>
</div>
```

To make it nicer, you can use the ternary operator:

```
<div class="other_left_array" >
    <a id="2" {{ followeds.followeds_posts_counts[key] > 0 ? 'style="display: none"' : '' }}  href="javascript:void(0);" class="left_array_trigger">
        la
    </a>
</div>
```

Or you can use the `{% spaceless %}` tag:

```
<div class="other_left_array" >
    {% spaceless %}
    <a
        id="2"
        {% if followeds.followeds_posts_counts[key] > 0 %}
            style="display: none"
        {% endif %}
        href="javascript:void(0);"
        class="left_array_trigger"
    >
    {% endspaceless %}
        la
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Wouter, the second solution using ternary operator is, IMHO, the best one.

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces how is the ternary the best? You are outputting a string or an empty string at all times. Using the first solution you only attempt to output something only if needed.

Comment: yeaaaah, you are right @crypticツ. I did a wrong calculation. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
<div class="other_left_array" >          
 <a id="2" {%if followeds.followeds_posts_counts[key]>0 %} style="display: none;"  {%endif%}     href="javascript:void(0);" class="left_array_trigger">
       la
    </a>             
 </div>
```