# Trying to make a button to show only for items that have a value set gor a variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, wordpress

I am having issues with a template being properly populated.

I have a store locator that lists pharmacies, and shows their correlating data (phone, address, hours of operation) + 3 buttons (view store, view flyer and Order Refill).

The function in the WordPress theme gets the data to be placed in the html template accordingly, for each item.

Order refill button is generated through a dynamic link that gets populated with the phone number and store name.

I am trying to achieve the following:

For stores that do not have the order refill (field id #no-order, value No / Empty), I want to hide the Order Refill button (id #order-refill-locator), and only show it for the stores that have the Refill field value as Yes - The data is being sent to the HTML template as
`{{order-refill}}`

```
if ($query->posts) {
    foreach ($query->posts as $result) {
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r(  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_hours", true) ); die;
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($result->ID), 'thumbnail' );
        if (!empty($src)) {
            $image = $src[0];
        } else {
            $image = get_site_url() . '/store_default.jpg';
        }

        $args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $result->ID, 'wpsl_store_category', $args );

        $term_categories = '';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $term_categories .= $term->slug . ', ';
        }
        $rs_categories = substr(trim($term_categories), 0, -1);

        $hours = get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_hours", true);

        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($result->ID);

        $store_data[]    =   array(
            'id'           =>  $result->ID,
            'name'         =>  $result->post_title,
            'description'  =>  $result->post_content,
            'lng'          =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_lng", true),
            'lat'          =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_lat", true),
            'address'      =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_address", true),
            'address2'     =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_address2", true),
            'link'         =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_url", true),
            'image'        =>  $image,
            'telephone'    =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_phone", true),
            'fax'          =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_fax", true),
            'email'        =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_email", true),
            'order-refill'      =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_refill", true),
            'city'         =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_city", true),
            'country'      =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_country", true),
            'zipcode'      =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_zip", true),
            'state'        =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_state", true),
            'hours'        =>  day($hours, 'monday'),  
            'hours1'       =>  day($hours, 'tuesday'),  
            'hours2'       =>  day($hours, 'wednesday'),  
            'hours3'       =>  day($hours, 'thursday'),  
            'hours4'       =>  day($hours, 'friday'),  
            'hours5'       =>  day($hours, 'saturday'),
            'hours6'       =>  day($hours, 'sunday'),
            'flyer'        =>  '/weekly-flyer/?store_code=' . get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_address2", true),
            'tag'          =>  $rs_categories,
            'category'     =>  $rs_categories,
            'href'         =>  get_permalink($result->ID),
            'color'        =>  trim('#005392'),
            'fontClass'    =>  trim('fa-map-marker'),
            'lat'          =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_lat", true),
            'lng'          =>  get_post_meta($result->ID, "wpsl_lng", true),
        );
    }
}
```

How can I make this happen? I have tried making the template as PHP even and adding an IF statement to possibly hide it that way, but without success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit: Template code below:

```
 <ul>
            <li data-markerid="{{markerid}}">
        <div class="img-store">
            <div class="loc-icon">
                 <svg width="25" height="22" viewBox="0 0 22 28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <g transform="translate(1 1)" stroke="#333" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <path d="M9.985 26.348S0 15.896 0 9.346C0 2.796 4.824 0 10.36 0c5.537 0 9.85 4.868 9.6 10.287-.25 5.42-9.975 16.06-9.975 16.06z"></path>
                    <ellipse cx="9.844" cy="9.643" rx="4.594" ry="4.5"></ellipse>
                  </g>
                </svg> {{distance}} {{length}}
            </div>
            <!--<div class="loc-dist">{{distance}} {{length}}</div>-->
        </div>

        <div class="list-details">
            <div class="list-content">
                <div class="loc-name">
                    <a href="{{href}}" target="_blank">{{name}}</a>

                </div>
                <div class="loc-addr">{{address}}</div> 
                <div class="loc-addr3">{{city}}, {{country}} {{zipcode}}</div>
                <div class="loc-phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> {{telephone}}</div>
                <div class="loc-hours"><span>Mon-Fri:</span> {{hours}}</div>
                <div class="loc-hours"><span>Sat:</span> {{hours6}}</div>
                <div class="loc-hours"><span>Sun:</span> {{hours5}}</div>
                <!--<div> <a href="">{{flyer}}</a></div>-->
                <div class="btn-tiny save-store-locator">

                    <a class="save-as" style="float: none;" onClick="saveStoreHeader(jQuery(this).data('lat'),jQuery(this).data('lng'));" href="javascript:void(0);" data-lat="{{lat}}" data-lng="{{lng}}" class="save-as" role="button">
                        Save as My Store
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="list-btn">
            <div class="btn-tiny location-buttons">
                <a href="{{href}}" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">VIEW DETAILS</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div> 
            <div class="btn-tiny location-buttons">
                <a href="{{flyer}}" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md tiny-btn-red tiny-small" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">VIEW FLYER</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="order-refill-locator" class="btn-tiny location-buttons" target="_blank">
                <a href="{{order-refill}}" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md tiny-btn-red" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">ORDER REFILL</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post the HTML template as this should only be done in the template not the PHP code.

Comment: Without the HTML template, I may not be able to help you. The solution doesn't lie in the PHP code.

Comment: Like the proverbial needle in the haystack, you’ve made it hard for people to find the error in your code. Your real problem lies only in a few instructions, and most of the code posted is completely irrelevant to the resolution of your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your template, just use a ternary operator to check if `{{ order-refill }}` contain any value.
like this

```
{{ order-refill ? '': '<div id="order-refill-locator" class="btn-tiny location-buttons" target="_blank">
                <a href="{{order-refill}}" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md tiny-btn-red" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">ORDER REFILL</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>' }}
```

or better yet, use the new PHP7 null coalesce operator

```
{{ order-refill ?? '<div id="order-refill-locator" class="btn-tiny location-buttons" target="_blank">
                <a href="{{order-refill}}" class="elementor-button-link elementor-button elementor-size-md tiny-btn-red" role="button">
                    <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                        <span class="elementor-button-text">ORDER REFILL</span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>' }}
```

correct me if i'm wrong on the usage of the null coalesce operator but the idea is, check if `{{ order-refill }}` contain any value, then show the `order-refill-locator` div. if not, just do nothing.

you already answered the question yourself :)

Comment: Thank you zimorok, I will give it a try in the morning, but that's the right idea.

Comment: Does not seem to be working. It shows the {{ order-refill ? }} with the content within ' ' no matter what the case scenario is. 

It's a HTML template, how can I make it recognize the operator?

Comment: as far as i know, `{{ }}` tag are the new templating system based on Twig. or you can do checking within the ternary operator like `{{ (!isset(order-refill)) ? '': <your code>}}` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820297/ternary-operators-in-twig-php-shorthand-form-of-if-then-else)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was able to resolve the issue by using CSS and calling the {{order-refill}} in the class, assign the content to display if value='Yes" and not if the value="No". But your input got me there and I will definitely dig deeper into it and get it working that way. Thanks!